# Using linq on a var

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method

```
public Task<IEnumerable<Order>> Search(Guid? advertiser, Guid? agency, string altOrder, int? channel, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate, bool? billable)
{
    var test= Search(channel, advertiser, agency, altOrder, null, null, null, startDate, endDate);
    return test;
}
```

It calls another method that returns an `<IEnumerable<Order>>` with a lot of data from a database.  I am trying to filter the data based on if it is invoiceable or not based on if billable is true or not.

I would  like to something similar to

```
Test.Where(x => x.Agency == air.agency && (billable == null || billable == air.invoiceable)).
```

I am trying to join on Agency from the results from the method I called and the air table.  From there filter based on invoiceable or not.  The statement above does not work, any ideas?

The statement does not work as I cannot get the code to compile.  .Where is not an extension of test.  What I am wondering if there is a work around to use .Where with test?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is `Test`?

Comment: `Test` is a `Task`, so you would need to get `Test.Result.Where()`, IMHO... but that won't work the way it is atm, because you have to do a task continuation, the naive call won't work as it is...

Comment: Please be as detailed as possible in your explanation of the problem.  When you say that your code fails to compile, you should provide the error message that you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i gotcha right  your  LINQ statement  wouldn't  work,  because your  linq  statement  is  not  clear.  If  you  want  query  filtered data and not at all(I mean whole set  of table data),  you should  write  like  that  some  mapped  model name  then `.Where(x => x.Agency == air.agency ).Take(10);` this  is a  first step  to load maximum 10 data  sample from Agency  table, then  u can  filter  again ask  to linq  to  be more specific , are these  data  invoice able or  not ?! :)